# Finding Intersection point value - area between curves

Tags: calculus, area

[image: Problem Image]

Consider the graphs of the functions $f(x) = $ $e^x + e^{-x} $ and $ g(x) = k|x| $, where k is a positive constant. If $ g(x) $ is tangent to the graph of $f$, find the area of the region bounded above by $f(x)$ and below by $g(x).$

How do I find the intersection point between the curves? Especially, what is k? I know when the two are tangent, their derivatives are equal to each other (slope). If I have k, I can find the intersection point, and I can find the area between the curves (use symmetry and double by 2).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Were you able to make any progress so far?

Comment: As a hint, do you have tangents for all possible values of $k$? Try to figure out for which.

Comment: I know that e^x-e^-x = k for x$>=$ 0, and e^x-e^-x = -k for x$<$ 0 because k|x| is a piecewise. But I am just confused on how to find this k. (Also sorry for formatting, I'm not sure how to do it) !

Comment: For $~x > 0, ~f'(x) = g'(x) \implies e^x - e^{-x} = k.~$ This implies that $~e^{2x} - ke^x - 1 = 0.~$ Letting $~u = e^x,~$ you have that $~u^2 - ku - 1 = 0.~$  This is a quadratic equation in $~u,~$ which implies that $~u~$ can be easily solved for as a function of $~k.~$

Comment: I have solved for x using quadratic formula in terms of u and then taking natural log. But this is still in terms of k.

Comment: $x$=$\ln (\frac{k \pm\sqrt{k^2+4}}{2})$

Comment: That is exactly what you want, expressing $~x_0~$ as a function of the **fixed constant** $~k.~$  Then, to compute the area, you could (for example) take $~2~$ times the area in the first quadrant, which would be $~2 \times \int_0^{x_0} (\text{something}) ~dx.$

Comment: It is not sufficient for the tangents to the graph to be parallel for the graphs to be tangent.

Answer (score 1):

So, after reading the question more carefully, I was able to figure out an answer. Thanks to everyone for trying, but it was actually easier than I thought.

So the problem says k is a positive constant.

$k \gt 0 $

$ f^\prime(x)$ $=$ $e^x-e^{-x}$, $g'(x) = k $ when $x \ge 0 $

Intersection Point (Restrict to First Quadrant, because we can use Symmetry)
$f(x) = g(x) $, $e^x+e^{-x} = kx $

And since $f'(x) = g'(x) $ because they are tangent,
$k = e^x-e^{-x}$
So we can do a substitution.

This will be the intersection point: $e^x + e^{-x} = (e^x-e^{-x}) (x) $

Now rearrange: $(e^x+e^{-x}) - (e^x-e^{-x})(x) = 0 $

Put that in a graphing calculator, you get $x = 1.1996786, -1.1996786 $

Since we restrict it to the first quadrant, we only use the positive value. Then, we find that $ k = e^{1.1996786} - e^{-1.1996786} = 3.017759123 $

Now we set up the integral for the area. Since we use symmetry, it would be

$2\int_{0}^{1.1996786} f(x) - g(x)  dx $ (First Quadrant)

$2\int_{0}^{1.1996786} e^x+e^{-x} - (3.017759123)x dx $

Which gives the area to be (rounded to the third decimal) $ **1.692** $

Comment: I have not read any of the two answers in detail, but the one by **AnCar** is clearly superior because it gives the result in closed form, and does so without the use of a calculator. Furthermore, notice that his/her answer does not match yours numerically.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Let me ask you this, do you find it intuitively clear that there is only one $k$ for which the graphs are tangent to each other? If so, I think it is not difficult to see that $k=e+1/e$ is that value and the graphs meet at $x=1$, since $f(1)=e+1/e=(e+1/e)\cdot 1=g(1)$. Also if you do find that intuitively clear, you can ignore the 'fancier' partial derivative stuff.

Comment: @astrid ah ok and now i see the issue. you substitute $k$ with $e^{x}-e^{-x}$. That is not correct. $e^{x}-e^{-x}$ is a function, not a number. What happens is that for a specific value of $x$, call it $x_0$, you have that $k=e^{x_0}-e^{-x_0}$. That clearly cannot hold for all $x$.

Comment: @AnCar: It is confusing a bit, but **astrid** uses $x$ as your $x_0$, so while the notation is unfortunate, its use is correct and is about solving a non-linear system of equations in $x$ (or $x_0$ in your notation) and $k$. The mistake must be somewhere else.

Comment: Huh, I checked with Desmos and the point is correct. I’m not sure what you mean when you can’t substitute $k$. We are allowed to use a graphing calculator for this problem.

Comment: If $k$ is $e + 1/e $ then it will be passing through the graph of $e^x + e^{-x} $. Plot it in a graphing calculator and take a look.

Comment: @AnCar: https://imgur.com/a/dnGo27e Take a look

Comment: @astrid you are absolutely correct. somehow i was looking for a trivial intersection point and forgot that there might be two. is $k=e+1/e$, there are indeed $2$. I think your solution is fine if you are allowed to use numerics. and as **Alex M.** pointed out, your notation confused me when you plug in the value of $k$. but you mean that as an equation for a particular $x$, and not as a functional equation.

Comment: @astrid there is another trick you can use if you want to get a more 'analytical' solution. the function $x\mapsto \tfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$ is the hyperbolic cotangent, $\coth$. Its Taylor expansion for example is known, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions. The equation for finding $x$ is simply $\coth x=x$. And indeed the positive solution is about $1.2$. So what you did looks fine. Well done!

Comment: Oh haha, interesting! Unfortunately I’m only taking AP Calculus BC, and this was an old quiz question. So I don’t think they would expect me to know this, lol. I think we learn Taylor Series later in the class tho.

Comment: @astrid Indeed, this is not something you can solve without a graphing calculator. The solutions for $\coth x= x$ are not 'nice numbers'.

Comment: @astrid And the point I was making with the Taylor series is that if you are looking for an approximate solution to $\coth x=x$, you could for example use the first two terms in the Taylor series, which would give you $1/x+x/3=x$, i.e., $x^2=3/2$ with positive solution $x \approx 1.22$.